# Is there a key difference between the principle of transfinite induction and the principle of transfinite induction for ordinals?

Tags: induction, set-theory, ordinals

In a recent question I was asked to prove the principle of transfinite induction for ordinals but I mistakenly proved the principle of transfinite induction, since I have a only a vague understanding of them, I was just wondering whether there is a key difference between the two or would a proof of the latter be acceptable to obtain all the marks. 
Thank you for any help.

Principle of transfinite induction: $\forall{x}<{z}(\forall{y} < x[\Phi(y)\rightarrow \Phi(x)]\rightarrow\forall{x}<z\Phi(x))$

Principle of transinite induction for ordinals;
$C \neq \phi,         \alpha,\beta\in{C}\forall{\alpha}\exists\beta[\alpha \leq \beta]$

Comment: Transfinite induction: Induction for every wellordered set. i.e. cardinals...

That's what I would say?

Comment: The premise of your question is that the names are confusing -- so you shouldn't expect a reader to know exactly what you mean by "the principle of transfinite induction". Please tell us the _actual statement that you proved_ rather than just the _name_ you use for that statement. If possible, please also do the same for the statement you now think you should have proved instead.

Comment: @menag "every wellordered set i.e. cardinals" — um, no: ordinals.

Comment: @BrianO What? I don't understand you.

Comment: I have edited it to include both definitions hope that helps

Comment: @menag That's because you don't understand ordinals and cardinals.

Comment: Do people think they are more or less equivalent and that a proof of the first one would suffice.

Comment: Neither of the things you have written seems to make much sense on its own. The second one does not seem to make sense at all. You really should write it explicitly, without using too much formal notation, in any case, but *especially* if you can't use it very well.

Comment: I dont really see whats wrong with the first one, isn't $\Phi(.)$ standard notation for a well defined property and for the second one maybe I should of specified that $\alpha, \beta $ were ordinals but apart from that it is pretty simple to understand.

Comment: @Stefan Perko Never said anything different.

Comment: @BrianO How exactly do you know that I don't understand them?
Cardinals are - being part of the ordinals - also wellordered. Now my guess was that transfinite induction might be the principle for general wellorders while transfinite induction for ordinals means the special case of ordinals.

Comment: Ok thank you, that was what I was after but do you think credit will be given if I proved the general case instead.

Comment: @Menag : I understand nothing of what they wrote. In particular it seems the point of all this is the "limit case" in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_induction probably the only point deserving to be discussed (and probably justifying the distinction ordinals/cardinals)

Comment: indeed all this is about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_ordinal (and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_cardinal )

Answer (score 0):

@user200632 Your transfinite induction principle is misstated. It ought to be:
$$
\forall x\in dom(\Phi))\, \big([(\forall y < x)\,\Phi(y)\to \Phi(x)] \big) \to (\forall x\in dom(\Phi))\, \Phi(x)
$$
for well-ordered $\Phi$ (in fact, for well-founded $\Phi$).

Your TI for ordinals is messed up: first you have $\alpha, \beta\in C$, then you quantify over them. Do you mean $(\forall\alpha \in C)(\exists \beta \in C)\, \alpha\le\beta$ ? That is trivially true (take $\beta = \alpha$) even for $C=\emptyset$, and you should get *no* points whatsoever for proving it :) It should be:
$$
(\exists\alpha \in C)(\forall \beta \in C)\, \alpha\le\beta \tag{$\emptyset \ne C\subseteq\sf{Ord}$}
$$